# WindowsMediaPlayer on Global.asax application_start

Tags: c#, asp.net, wmplib

i have this basic code to play a mp3 file on a aspx page.

```
    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
    player.URL = "file's url"
    player.controls.play();
```

now this works if i put it on a button's click event or something.
But nothing happens if i put these codes to Application_Start event in Global.asax file.

What i am trying to achieve here is that, when someone loads the page, they don't start listening the song from the beginning, but start listening from the song's current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, There is quite a bit wrong with this I don't know where to start.

1) You are using vb script code in a browser and assuming the user has that control.  This won't work on most browsers and most operating systems.

2) Application on start does not know a user's state.  At that point there is no user only the system process itself.

You need to use some client side code such as javascript or flash.  ASP.net cannot play music to a browser natively by itself,  it just won't work.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but quick question. what do you mean by vb script code ?